# ¿Puedo duplicar una pregunta en StackOverflow en español en el servidor inglés?

Tags: soporte, idiomas, idioma-español

Si tengo una pregunta en StackOverflow en español que lleva varios días sin respuesta, ¿está permitido publicar la misma pregunta en StackOverflow en inglés traducida al inglés?

Comment: Si, totalmente, no somos celosos. Ahora, si te responden en el sitio en inglés sería estupendo que traduzcas esa respuesta luego. Saludos.

Comment: armate la respuesta @PatricioMoracho

Comment: Te sugiero revises los enlaces que comparte Patricio en su respuesta, tal vez necesitas modificar el formato de tu pregunta y agregar más información para que esta tenga exito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mientras respetes las premisas de una buena pregunta en cada comunidad claro que puedes.

Revisa

[**¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

y su versión en idioma inglés:

[**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Incluso sería muy bien recibido que te tomes el trabajo luego de traducir cualquier eventual buena respuesta que recibas.